Finding a suitable $\delta$ for $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs for third degree polynomials
In class my professor went through an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the limit $$\lim_{x\to 4} (x^3 -8x^2 + 16x + 4) = 4.$$
He found a suitable $\delta = \min \left\{1, \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{5}} \right\}.$ Thus $|f(x) - L|=|x||x-4|^2 < 5|x-4|^2<\varepsilon.$ Note that $f(x) = x^3 -8x^2 + 16x + 4$ and $L = 4.$
I asked him if, instead of letting $\delta = \min \left\{1, \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{5}} \right\},$ we could let $\delta = \min \left\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{5} \right\},$ considering that $|f(x) - L| = |x||x-4||x-4|,$ we could use that fact that $|x|<5$ and $|x-4|<1$ to conclude that $|f(x) - L|<5|x-4|<5\frac{\varepsilon}{5}=\varepsilon.$
He gave me a flat out no, without any further explanation. Granted, he had more important things to go through. I wanted to know if my reasoning is correct or if this isn't actually allowed.

For $0\lt \epsilon\lt 5$, you have $0\lt\frac{\epsilon}{5}\lt 1$, so $\frac{\epsilon}{5}\lt\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{5}}$; and if $\epsilon\geq 5$, then both $\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{5}}$ are greater than $1$, so your choice also works.

As the two comments above show, if you can find a smaller bound, and $\min{1,\frac \epsilon 5}\le \min{1,\sqrt{\frac \epsilon 5}}$, than I way that works, than your way will work even without doing any math.  So your way will work. But I want to point out 1) your reasoning is valid and stands on its own. 2) Even if you found a bound larger than the accepted one, that might still be valid if the accepted one is not the absolute minimal. (And BTW finding the absolute minimal bound is a useless and pointless and unnecessary endeavor.)

Yes, your reasoning seems to work.
Here's another way to see it, which amounts to the same thing.  If the professor's choice of $\delta$ is $\delta_1 = \min\{1,\sqrt{\epsilon/5}\}$ and yours is $\delta_2 = \min\{1,\epsilon/5\}$, then $\delta_2\leq\delta_1$.  Hence $(4-\delta_2,4+\delta_2)\subset(4-\delta_1,4+\delta_1)$.  In particular, if $x\in(4-\delta_2,4+\delta_2)$, then $x\in(4-\delta_1,4+\delta_1)$, and by the professor's work it follows that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.
